# How to securely determine if user is logged in using client-session

Tags: javascript, node.js, session, authentication

I'm using this package for user sessions: https://www.npmjs.com/package/client-sessions

Logging in is going great, but I'm not sure if I'm checking that my users are logged in correctly and securely. I believe the sessions are encrypted, but it seems like just checking `if(req.session && req.session.user)` is insufficiently secure. Is this the right way to check if a user is logged in? To be clear, users are being logged in and kicked out after the 30 minutes I've indicated, but I'm not much of a hacker and I don't want people just modifying their cookies to get into other users' accounts.

```
var session = require('client-sessions');

app.use(session({
    cookieName: 'session',
    secret: config.secret,
    duration: 30 * 60 * 1000,
    activeDuration: 5 * 60 * 1000
}));

router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
if(req.session && req.session.user)
    return res.redirect('amazingpage');
else
    res.render('index');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Like you said just checking user supplied data is unsafe for this purpose.

Typically the server saves informations like this in a session and hands out a [Session Cookie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie#Session_management) with a unique (and random) id via the SSL tunnel. If the User supplies a different id it is extremely likely to not exist and therefore not cause any harm. The SSL tunnel is important here so a "Man in the Middle" cannot read the id and claim the session as his own. See [Session Hijacking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_hijacking).

If you do not want to store any more information on the server than absolutely nececcary you could also encrypt this data with a secret key only known by the server and store the cipher on the client like done to prevent SYN flooding. See [SYN cookies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SYN_cookies). Be sure to use a cipher mode that prevents the user from modifying the cookie if taking this aproach. (Typically [CBC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Cipher_Block_Chaining_.28CBC.29) is used)